# Can I build WCF servers using Delphi 2010?

Tags: wcf, delphi, delphi-2010

We would like to build new application as multi tiers, we can do it as web service, but we prefer to use more advanced features as WCF, which not found in datasnap too.

can we do that with Delphi 2010 win32?

the clients will be Delphi win32, Asp.Net (C#) and maybe windows mobile phones too.

Answer (score 2):

Using Delphi Prism you can, see http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinB4.htm

Answer (score 1):

Since WCF is a .NET only technology, you will need to bridge to cross from the unmanaged Win32 world to the managed .NET world.

There are a few options to get started.
All of them feel kludge-like, so it might be better to ask yourself the question "what features of WCF are so compelling over web services?"

Here it goes:

- Write a .NET wrapper, export it as COM or ActiveX, then use it either as COM or ActiveX object from native Delphi Win32
- Use Delphi Prism with the [UnmanagedExport attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273141/how-can-i-pass-a-delphi-string-to-a-prism-dll) to create a .NET wrapper that you can call from native Delphi Win32
- Use [Managed VCL](http://www.managed-vcl.com/) to do .NET interop from native Delphi Win32
- From another Stackoverflow question: [create a C++ DLL crossing the bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients) this used "[mixed mode C++](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/mixed_mode_delphi.html)"
- Use [RemObjects Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx) on both the C# or Delphi Prism and native Delphi Win32 side (RemObjects wrote Delphi Prism, so this works like a charm)

The last one might be the real one you are after:
it can do much more than web-services, but is not as platform limited as WCF is.

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

[WCF is a part of .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx), you need an .NET language to use it: No "Win32" language can do it. Delphi Prism can!