# I have a c sharp dll. How can I make it usable in other languages, such as PHP or Delphi?

Tags: c#, php, delphi, dll, assemblies

I have a dll developed in C Sharp. How can I make it usable in other languages, such as PHP or Delphi?

I cannot find any solution to this problem yet. Isn't there any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 9):

If Delphi can understand COM, then you can make a [COM wrapper around the .NET DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx?display=Print).

I am doing this now for an older IDE which doesn't understand .NET, but it understands COM so I am able to use the latest .NET features in my older applications.

Comment: Yes, forgot about that route.

Comment: This is probably the best way, and Delphi *can* understand COM.  It's got COM interface support built in as a language feature.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to COM, you could try these (from my [Delphi Win32 to WCF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279925/can-i-build-wcf-servers-using-delphi-2010)) for Delphi Win32:

- Use Delphi Prism with the [UnmanagedExport attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273141/how-can-i-pass-a-delphi-string-to-a-prism-dll) to create a .NET wrapper that you can call from native Delphi Win32
- Use [Managed VCL](http://www.managed-vcl.com/) to do .NET interop from native Delphi Win32
- From another Stackoverflow question: [create a C++ DLL crossing the bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients) this used "[mixed mode C++](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/mixed_mode_delphi.html)"
- Use [RemObjects Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx) on both the C# or Delphi Prism and native Delphi Win32 side (RemObjects wrote Delphi Prism, so this works like a charm)

The last one might be the real one you are after.

For PHP it is a different story;

- PHP might run on a non-Windows box,
- there are [.NET implementations of PHP](http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php) that would allow for direct linking of your C# assembly DLL

--jeroen