# How can I pass a Delphi array of integers to a Prism DLL?

Tags: arrays, delphi, dll, delphi-prism, oxygene

I've read and successfully tried the answer to [How can I pass a Delphi string to a Prism DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273141/how-can-i-pass-a-delphi-string-to-a-prism-dll), but wondered if it was possible to use a similar method to pass a Delphi array of integers (static or dynamic) to a Prism DLL.

Comment: `UnmanagedType.LPArray` seems a likely starting point for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest (without marshalling) is to encode the array using BASE16 or BASE64 into a unicode string and pass a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write a full working example but here are the key things to adapt the example you mention in the other question:

declare a type with your buffer length

```
type
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
  TBuffer = array[0..-length-]of integer;
```

and to make operations in the buffer remember to use the "pinned" modifier

```
var BufferPointer: ^TBuffer; pinned;
```

...

```
  BufferPointer := @the_buffer[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm useless at this an would really appreciate a full example if anyone has the time and willing. Your minutes will save me hours. Not in any rush.